# NServiceBus not creating queues automatically (MSMQ)

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I'm doing the examples from the NServiceBus website (http://docs.particular.net/samples/step-by-step/) and when I run in Visual Studio everything works and the queues are created automatically (even if I delete them and re-run the solution than they get created automatically). The dev machine runs Windows 8.

I have an emulated Windows 2008 RC2 - when I take my solution bin folder to the server machine and try to run NServiceBus.Host.exe it eventually crashes and the reason is: "The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation" - even when I run with administrative privileges. When looking the the queue I see that they were not created, and if I manually create the queues than it works.

Why doesn't queues get created automatically when I run on a different machine?

**Update**

If I run `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install` than it creates the queues, and also installs it a s windows service. But what I would like to do is run it regularly. If I just run the exe, is it considered as self hosted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the NServiceBus.Host.Exe with NServiceBus.Integration argument, that should create your queues...

For more info on profiles [take a look here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/more-on-profiles)
and [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles)

HTH