# Set up NServiceBus queues in EndpointConfig.cs

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

Similar but different from 
[NServiceBus not creating queues automatically (MSMQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500844/nservicebus-not-creating-queues-automatically-msmq)

When running in debug mode in Visual Studio I get:

```
>...NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqQueueCreator Could not create queue error@
```

I'm using NServiceBus 5.2.7  and Host 6.0.0

and wanted to know how to configure this in the EndpointConfig.cs because I was not able to find the  .Configure.With()...

(its probably a using... helper issue)

meanwhile I got an answer from the tech guys... so here comes my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio if run as Administrator (with windows administrator rights) will do everything automatically.

For a real installation in any case you'll be using the installer.
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/#installation